# Как реализовать "ленивую загрузку" в route, если компонентов много?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

в route.js такая структура

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/category',
      component: Category,
      children: {
        { path: '', component: CategoryList },
        { path: '/view', component: CategoryView },
        { path: '/edit', component: CategoryEdit },
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/post',
      component: Post,
      children: {
        { path: '', component: PostList },
        { path: '/view', component: PostView },
        { path: '/edit', component: PostEdit },
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

чтобы Post компонент загрузилось отдельно я делаю вот так

```
const Post= resolve => {
  require.ensure(['@/views/post/'], () => {
    resolve(
        require('@/views/post/')
    )
  })
}
```

а как делать чтобы не только Post компонент и ещё его дочерний компоненты тоже с ним вместо загрузилось отдельно? 
Итак мне нужно чтобы когда заходили в компонент Post, нужно загрузить Post компонент и его дочерний компоненты сразу вместе

Comment: в `require.ensure` можно передать массив строк. Пробовали?

Comment: нет...не пробовал.....а это как? можете пример показать?

Comment: массив строк? `['@/views/post/', '@/views/postlist/', '@/views/postedit/']`  https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require-ensure

Comment: нет...я имел в виду общий пример. например здесь что возвращать?
`require('@/views/post/')`

Comment: `require.ensure` - я никогда не пользовался. Только что почитал документацию. Почитайте и Вы - поэксперементируйте

Answer (score 0):

Итак я нашел ответа. Если кому нибудь нужен пример вот [здесь](https://alligator.io/vuejs/lazy-loading-routes/#combining-routes):

```
const Post = r => require.ensure([], () => r(
    require('@/views/post/')
), 'post-pages')
const PostView = r => require.ensure([], () => r(
    require('@/views/post/view')
), 'post-pages')
const PostEdit = r => require.ensure([], () => r(
    require('@/views/post/edit')
), 'post-pages')
```

и в оф.док тоже есть [пример](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5) но я его не очень понял. Если знайте, подскажите